# what's the latest STRAIGHT SCOOP on bluetooth for Python 3.7.3 using WIN64

Tags: python, bluetooth, win64

What is the latest STRAIGHT SCOOP on Bluetooth using Python 3.7.3 on a WIN64.

Still can't find reliable documentation that isn't confusing because of "Linux only" solutions or 2.7 solutions.  for example "AF_bluetooth" apparently not supported for WIN64.  Would appreciate ANY proven info on code, documentation, examples, links to GOOD info for WIN64.  My project for a Bluetooth link between a Surface Pro 4 and my PIC18F67K40 with HC_05 or HC-06 is badly in need and overdue for a solution.

this works, but after this what works?

sample working program:

```
# test program to receive data from a PIC18F67K40/HC-06 server.

import bluetooth

target_name = "HC-06"
target_address = None

nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()

for bdaddr in nearby_devices:
    if target_name == bluetooth.lookup_name( bdaddr ):
        target_address = bdaddr
        break

if target_address is not None:
    print ("found target bluetooth device with address ", target_address)
else:
    print ("could not find target bluetooth device nearby")
    exit

print ("ready to start listening subroutine")
```

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question than the vague "What's the straight scoop?" Don't post a working program, post a non-working program and explain what the problem is.

Comment: Read my question again because it sounds like you have not experienced the Bluetooth problem with python3.7/WIN64.  If you had, you would understand the question and not replied as you did.  I'm just trying to separate all the bad scoop on python Bluetooth for win64 from the "STRAIGHT SCOOP".  If you have some positive input I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Please read [ask] to see how to ask a proper question on SO.

Comment: I know nothing about the Bluetooth problem, but that's not the point. Questions need to explain the problem clearly, and show the code that you're having problems with. Not just ask general questions. There should be the possibility of an objectively correct answer that you can accept. Also, requests for documentation or libraries are explicitly off-topic.

Comment: let me try again to explain the problem.  It isn't that my code doesn't work.  The problem is basically documentation being old, obsolete, confusing as to which python, platform, imports, and any number of incompatibilities in trying to do Bluetooth coding in Python 3.7.n on the WIN64 platform.  Available documentation that I have been able to find does not always clearly specify which Python version, imports, and platform that it works with.  It's like trying to guess at the code for a combination lock when trying to code python Bluetooth programming.  The existing information is very poor

Comment: From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): **Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.**